# is it faster to update a row or search in the table?

Tags: database

I use **SQL server** as a database and I want to know Regardless of the database I use or I mean in general

I had a scenario in an auction website and I wanted to always have the highest price that the user entered, I added an attribute named **"Highest Price"** to the **item** entity (which is the item that is being sold), and checked that if the user entered a higher price it will be updated

so my question is, was it faster to do this or that I have a table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re58A.png) and search in it every time I insert a new record

Comment: Measure it ....

Comment: am in a software engineer class and it's a part of it I still didn't use a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My direct answer to your question (as you put it into a title) would definitely be searching, as writing takes longer time than reading.

So, here are your two options for your example (that is, if you want to actually identify the user that made the highest bid, and I guess you would do):

- Use the "bids" table.
  Advantages: Allows you to keep history of bids, adds coherence (totally makes sense linking users and items in a table).
  Disadvantages: Way slower as to find the maximum price you need to search using MAX(), plus you will need to write each entry, regardless its price.
- Add two attributes to the table that contains the items, referring to the highest price and the user ID that put that price.
  Advantages: Faster, you select directly one row and you only write given certain conditions.
  Disadvantages: Doesn't look too coherent linking the user to an item, rather than to a bid.

Common things to both options: You write data to two columns, although with different intensity.

If you need absolutely the highest speed possible, go for the second one, but, especially when you're engineering software, you must also take coherence into account.